# IIS not reconizing Bootstrap CSS and Javascript

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, twitter-bootstrap, iis

When i'am runing the application in visual studio 2010 i have no problem whith boostrap CSS and javascript, otherwise, when i publish it, all the javascript and css is not recognized. I create a simple html page to test 
if it is a html formatt problem, but the problem still happen. Does anyone can help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="Styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>
            Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">
            Use this document as a way to quickly start     any new project.<br>
            All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            Ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly happens? What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: I see a the page whithout the css format.

Comment: What do you see in the console and network tab?

Comment: No erros, Warnings or Information in Console TAB. And Network tab don't show anything.

Comment: Refresh the page and look at the requests in the network tab.

Comment: Making what you sugest, i can se that the IIS return the CSS content. But why IE dont use this content to show the page correct? Have you have another sugest?

Comment: URL    Protocol Method Result Type  Received Taken
http://localhost:97/  HTTP  GET 200 text/html 1.14 KB 32 ms refresh
/Styles/bootstrap.min.css HTTP  GET 200 text/csss 114.78 KB 31 ms
/Styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css HTTP  GET 200 text/csss 19.72 KB 15 ms

Comment: `text/csss` is the wrong MIME type.

Comment: Thanks Slaks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is due to windows features in IIS not being turned on to support static content such as CSS and JS.

The steps to enable this are:

1. Go to “Turn Windows features on or off”
2. Select Internet Information Services
3. Select World Wide Web Services
4. And check Static Content

Comment: The Static Content status is Installed. I think that it is not the problem, because i have others sites in ISS and no off them have problem with static content. All of then uses CSS and Javascript and i have no problem with then.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the path to your css/javascript relative using the ~.

```
<link href="~/Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or by using ResolveURL

```
<link href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Styles/bootstrap.min.css") %>' rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: The problem was the MIME type of the CSS in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

The problema was the mime Type of files .css in the site of ISS. It was set to "text/csss", but the correct is "text/css".